# Push data from bitbucket pipeline to ECS as volume

Tags: amazon-ecs, docker-volume, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to set up a Bitbucket pipeline to run PHP application. The application itself will be running using separate containers for `nginx` and `php-fpm` so both will need application source code directory to operate similar to this snippet:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "php-app",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/php-app"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "nginx-proxy-conf",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/proxy/conf.d"
      }
    }  
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "php-app",
      "image": "php:fpm",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "php-app",
          "containerPath": "/var/www/html",
          "readOnly": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "nginx-proxy",
      "image": "nginx",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "php-app"
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "php-app",
          "containerPath": "/var/www/html",
          "readOnly": true
        },
        {
          "sourceVolume": "nginx-proxy-conf",
          "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/conf.d",
          "readOnly": true
        },
        {
          "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-nginx-proxy",
          "containerPath": "/var/log/nginx"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

(source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecstutorial.html )

For this reason I don't want to embed application source within images (I could run `COPY` to both `nginx` and `php-fpm` but it wouldn't be nice) and I would like to have source stored within a volume.

The question is: how can I push application after it's built (I have custom bitbucket agent with composer and stuff) to ECR so that I can use it in task definition?

Comment: So you want to _build_ an application image(s) using Pipelines, not run it, right? Because for running it there's `BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR`...

Comment: I want to create images, push them to ECR, define task and service and then run...

Comment: And you know that you can run `docker build` and `docker volume create` in Pipelines, right? There's also this https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/amazon-ecs-now-supports-docker-volume-and-volume-plugins/ which might be a good idea.

Comment: I didn't think of `volume create` in fact. :) Can you post it as an answer so that I can mark as solution?

Comment: Actually, I don't think this will help because ECR only allows you to store images, not volumes. You could pack the source code in an image and then share that code with other running containers using a shared volume, but it'd be quite flaky.

Comment: So you'd need to push the source to S3 and then use that as a shared volume. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764448/adding-s3-bucket-as-docker-volume